# Selecting nested iframes with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, nested

I'm trying to automate the filling out of an Easily Apply job application on Indeed. [Here](http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=2e3d019aa34a2801&q=bartender&tk=1a9g51n08a3iof6h&from=web&advn=5333586156877432&sjdu=UvkB_mgi5f7NyMagFcTHP0E6zA3mclLGHWb8Kte-0FV3cY2ZuZvj3LUvh8wnnxrqeYWG3HpvTXBK3G4htWfwgfQeMa0N1Tds6VxYb4V3Vlg&pub=4a1b367933fd867b19b072952f68dceb) is an example of a job application on Indeed that uses the Easily Apply approach. I've tried every which way to navigate the nested iframes; however, I cannot find an approach that works. I even found that this question has been asked before, unfortunately, the solution given to the question does not work for me. Below is my code as it stands now:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('indeed_url_goes_here')

driver.find_element_by_class_name('indeed-apply-button').click()
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/iframe'))
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="indeedapply-modal-preload-iframe"]'))
driver.find_element_by_class_name('applicant.name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the first parent `iframe` and switch to it and then to the nested frame by index.

Complete working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=2e3d019aa34a2801&q=bartender&tk=1a9g51n08a3iof6h&from=web&advn=5333586156877432&sjdu=UvkB_mgi5f7NyMagFcTHP0E6zA3mclLGHWb8Kte-0FV3cY2ZuZvj3LUvh8wnnxrqeYWG3HpvTXBK3G4htWfwgfQeMa0N1Tds6VxYb4V3Vlg&pub=4a1b367933fd867b19b072952f68dceb")

driver.find_element_by_class_name('indeed-apply-button').click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[name$=modal-iframe]")))

driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1.jobtitle").text)
```

Prints the job title from the popup: `Bartender/Mixologist`.

Comment: When I try this, I get a NoSuchFrameException. Unable to locate frame.

Comment: This method results in a timeout exception. I tried playing around with the /html/body/iframe xpath and still get the timeout exception.

Comment: @Mandeep are you putting it after clicking the apply button?

Comment: Thanks! It works in Firefox. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with PhantomJS, but I think that can be fixed with another explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, the element doesn't have a class name - it has a regular name and an ID, so use either `driver.find_element_by_name`or `driver.find_element_by_id`.

Comment: Thanks. I had typed most of the code from memory. I'm surprised their weren't other errors.